# PowerBI Reports/Dashboard in Visual Studio C# Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, desktop-application, powerbi

I am developing a project which uses FORMS to get data from user and store in SQL SERVER, now I have made reports on PowerBI Desktop version.

Is it possible that instead of opening PowerBI every time, I can access/import my Reports/Dashboard into Visual Studio Project being developed in C#,

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, but it sounds like you're after [PowerBI Embedded](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-integrate-report/) (example: [github project](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp))

Comment: The link you mentioned is for Web App/WebForm, i am talking about Desktop App i cannot find any source where i can use the PowerBI reports/Dashboard in my c# WinForm

Comment: You can embed an iFrame in your winforms app.